# ReactDOM.render inside $.post error callback

Tags: javascript, post, reactjs, react-dom

I am new to React and trying to render an error message when a POST request returns an error. Something like this:

```
$.post({
    url: `/abc/xyz/`,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (response) {    
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div>
                <p>response.statusText</p>
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('errorDialog')
        );
    }
});
```

However, when I try to run it, in the console I keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
```

Closer inspection shows the problem to be in the line `ReactDOM.render` inside the error callback. Can this not be used inside the callback? I tried using it outside but possibly due to the async nature of callback functions, it doesn't work. Does someone know how I can fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using React, why are you still using jQuery? Almost everything it does React and plain modules do instead. For things like posting, use a universal module like `superagent` or the fetch API... As for your error: per its text, step one is to not minify your code, so you can see *where* the error is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all looks like you are getting the `Minified exception occurred` error because `ReactDOM` didn't find the element with the id of `errorDialog`, next you are using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` based on your  settings... I suggest you setup one state for the `statusText` and save the value you are getting there. I've prepared an example for you. ES6:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      statusText: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST'
        url: `/abc/xyz/`,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
          console.log("$.post success", response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          this.setState({
            statusText: response.statusText
          });
        }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    const { statusText } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{statusText}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('errorDialog'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've flipped the $.post with $.ajax.  Your function format is for $.ajax, not $.post

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/